# Geoserver POST filter to WMS layer

Tags: geoserver, wms

I have a filter that is currently used in URL, but it became more complicated and exceeds allowed URL length.

Is there a way to make a POST request with filter definition in a request body?

I tried to send following body, but without success. Tile is displayed, but not filtered.

```
<Filter xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <PropertyName>key1</PropertyName>
        <Literal>a</Literal>
    </PropertyIsEqualTo>
</Filter>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a CQL filter and post the request as a form instead of as a URL, but with the same key and values as a normal GET.